# Can't get Composer to work on Windows

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois in my PHP scripts, but can't get it to work. I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to using Composer.

This is what I tried:

- Cloned the git repo locally
- Installed Composer for Windows
- In Powershell, navigated to the local repository
- Typed `composer require`. Composer first asked me: `Search for a package:`, where I simply pressed `ENTER`. Then, Composer installed various packages in the vendor directory (phpunit, symfony, sebastian, etc.), and it created an `autoload.php` file.

But if I include that `autoload.php` in my example script (the basic example on the phpWhois Github main page), it generates the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'phpWhois\Whois' not found in /home/myServer/www/myApp/api/whoistest.php on line 12

Well, the Installation manual on the Github page says I should run

```
php composer.phar require "phpwhois/phpwhois":"~4.0"
```

So I tried the following in the Powershell console:

```
composer require "phpwhois/phpwhois":"~4.0"
```

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>
> Could not parse version constraint :~4.0: Invalid version string ":~4.0"

Then this:

```
composer require "phpwhois/phpwhois"
```

> Problem 1
>
> - Conclusion: remove phpwhois/phpwhois dev-master
> - Can only install one of: phpwhois/phpwhois[dev-master, 4.2.3].
> - Can only install one of: phpwhois/phpwhois[dev-master, 4.2.4].
> - Can only install one of: phpwhois/phpwhois[v4.2.5, dev-master].
> - Installation request for phpwhois/phpwhois dev-master -> satisfiable by phpwhois/phpwhois[dev-master].
> - Installation request for phpwhois/phpwhois ^4.2 -> satisfiable by phpwhois/phpwhois[4.2.3, 4.2.4, v4.2.5].

Then this:

```
composer require "phpwhois/phpwhois:~4.0"
```

which gave the same error as above.

I tried various other syntaxes to specify the version here, but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's  start from the beginning.

1. Download the latest `composer.phar` from [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (scroll down to *manual install*).
2. Put it in your project root directory.
3. Remove all your current require statements from your `composer.json`.
4. Open a terminal and navigate to your project root.
5. Execute `php composer.phar require phpwhois/phpwhois`.
6. Execute `php composer.phar install`.
7. Include the autoloader in your code: `require vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: Thank you, I just followed these steps. However, I still get the same `Fatal error: Class 'phpWhois\Whois' not found in /home/myServer/www/myApp/api/whoistest.php on line 12` error. How can I get more information about this error?

Comment: Ah it seems the `use phpWhois\Whois` statement from the example is not necessary. If I remove that statement, it works fine.

Comment: I think you should read up on namespaces in PHP =) You either use a class, or call it using a fully qualified name, but not both.